# Ignoring an entity field

Tags: scala, squeryl

I have an entity declared as

```
case class Snippet(id: Long,
                    name: String,
                    text: String,
                    @Column("created_at") createdAt: Date,
                    @Column("user_id") userId: Option[Long],
                    @Transient author: Option[User]
) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {

  def this() = this(0, "", "", new Date(), Some(0), Some(new User()))
}
```

but Squeryl 0.9.5-6 still fails with `java.lang.RuntimeException: field type models.squeryl.User is not supported`. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like squeryl isn't picking up the `@Transient`. Try a meta-annotation, `@(Transient @field)`?

Answer (score 0):

BTW, should this field be inside the case class? Does it have to be included in `hashCode`, `equals` methods?

I never tested this, but maybe this will work, too:

```
case class Snippet(something: Int)(author: Option[User])
```

Then again, maybe it doesn't work.. I'll delete this comment if that isn't compatible with squeryl..